# Does this property of $f(x)$ have a particular name?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ have distances denoted $d$ and $d'$ respectively, let $f: X \to Y$ be a function, and let $x_0 \in X$. Then $f$ is said to be *continuous* at $x_0$ if, given any real number $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists a real number $\delta \gt 0$ such that if $x \in X$ and $d(x, x_0) \lt \delta$, then $d'(f(x), f(x_0)) \lt \epsilon$, where $\epsilon = \delta(\epsilon)$.

If we restrict ourselves to a simple function $f(x): \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ for $x \in \Bbb R$, we notice that for every $x_0$ in the domain of $f$ there exists another $x$ arbitrarily close to it. Thus, we need only look at the *range* of $f$ to spot any discontinuities.

Does this property have a name, or is it just an example of a bijective function?

Comment: Revise before posting...... Your second paragraph is unclear

Comment: "every $x$ value in the domain is continuous" makes no sense. continuity is not a property of points but a property of functions, which may or may not hold at particular points. this is like saying "$4$ is continuous" or "$-3/7$ is differentiable."

Comment: @Neel I made some corrections, I hope it makes some sense now

Comment: @symplectomorphic You are correct. I knew that it didn't make sense, I just didn't have a better term to describe it. I changed my phrasing a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: perhaps what you are trying to imagine is what continuity could mean for functions on a discrete metric space such as the integers rather than on a metric space such as the reals. the answer is that *every* function on a discrete space is continuous.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I am unfortunately unfamiliar with discrete metric spaces, could you elaborate on what you mean?